# How to change color bar in R barplot?

Tags: r

I'd like to change color of only Goodyear and the bar. Thanks in advance
Here is the code that I used to get graph

```
library(readxl)
bist <- read_excel("A7.xlsx", sheet=1)
bistOrder <- bist[order(bist$SECTOR),]
bistRE <- bistOrder[c(293:295),]
bistREorder <- bistRE[order(as.numeric(bistRE$FA)),]
bistREorder$FA <- as.numeric(bistREorder$FA)
s <- strsplit(bistREorder$COMPANY, " ")
x1 = lapply(s, function(x) x[[1]])
RE <- bistREorder
rownames(RE) <- unlist(x1)
par(mai=c(1,2,1,1))
barplot(log(RE$FA), horiz=T, names.arg=rownames(RE), las=1, 
    main="Size Distribution in tyre products Sector",
    xlab="Log Fixed Assets")
```

[image: The graph]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Stackoverflow is a site for programming questions. If you want help with your code, you need to show your code, and reduce it to a minimal example. If you just want help with how to use some software made for users, unfortunately that's probably off-topic here.

Comment: To color the bar(s) you can barplot(log(RE$FA), ..., col=c("blue", "red", yellow"))

Comment: Also, please try to understand the difference between R and RStudio. This question has nothing to do with RStudio.